# Why does my jar can't open from the task Scheduler

Tags: java, windows-7

I'm trying to start a jar after my login has proceeded.
This action is performed by the Task Scheduler from Windows.
When I run this jar from his own directory it works properly.
When I'm logged in, the JVM gives me the following error:
"Could not find main class" and the directory of my jar.
I already set up the main class in the manifest.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about how you start the jar? What do you mean by 'when I'm logged in the JVM'?

Comment: How are you trying to load the JAR? Via the command line? Via a custom class loaded?

Comment: I'm loading this via Task Scheduler from Windows.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are using Task Scheduler in Windows to do this

Comment: I used Task Scheduler,made a new task, set a trigger and as action I set the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advise you to create .bat file with described classpath and else environments properties.
Most popular problems with missed JAVA_HOME property.
.bat file with described JAVA_HOME will help you to avoid any such problems.

Another way — just check does JAVA_HOME are setted it your system env settings.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` lets you know where Java is installed, it does not tell Java where the classes it should load are located...